# Migration MSSql Db - from SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise backup can restore in SQL Server 2008 R2 Express version

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express, backup-strategies

I have a quick simple question: can a `SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise/ Developer edition` backup be restored in a `SQL Server 2008 R2 Express` version?

- Source: SQL Server 2008 R2

  10.50.1600.1    RTM Developer Edition (64-bit)
- Destination: SQL Server 2008 R2 Express 64bit (I just download setup right now, so don't know about other details.)

Also what feature will effect if we migrate from `Enterprise or Developer edition to Express version` like we used

```
- FTS(Full-Test search) 
- Reporting services 
- SSRS 
- SSIS 
- SQL job for auto backup etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there **is no** SQL Server **Ultimate** edition - we have Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise, Developer and that's about it. Your source server is a **Developer** edition.

But **yes** - as long as the destination's version (2008 R2) is identical (or newer), you can restore a backup from a source server (here also 2008 R2).

You just can **never go back** in time - your backup from **2008 R2** cannot be restored on **2008** or **2005** (or even older ones)

**Update:**

- FTS(Full-Test search) : included in SQL Server 2008 R2 **Express with Advanced Services**
- Reporting services : included in SQL Server 2008 R2 **Express with Advanced Services**
- SSRS : included in SQL Server 2008 R2 **Express with Advanced Services**
- SSIS : import/export wizard and basic adapters included in all Express versions
- SQL job for auto backup etc.: SQL Server **Express** does **not** support SQL Server Agent jobs

See [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc645993.aspx) for a **detailed** matrix of which features are included in which editions

Comment: Thanks, Is advanced services version is free? and also give me link for download.

Comment: @Ajay2707: **yes** - all **Express** editions are free - and you can download them all from the [SQL Server Express web page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/Products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) at Microsoft